# Tell Google to recrawl external pages whose low quality links to my site have been removed

Tags: seo, google, backlinks

I had some bad backlinks removed recently from some weird link directories. They are low quality pages and have a cache date which is at least 2 months old. I was wondering if there would be a way to get those sites crawled by Google as fast as possible to let google know that those links have been removed.

Would it for example work If I create a page on some domain with links to those low quality pages and let Google crawl the page I made?

Comment: In found this link, which seems to be a way to submit site to google for re-indexing. https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals?pli=1

Answer (score 1):

Interesting thought, however, I would not link to a low quality site. You would be, in a real sense, validating that site.

Unfortunately, you cannot get Google to index another site. It is just not possible. Search engines are notoriously slow. The reason is simple. The web is just so vast that, even for Google, it takes at least 10 months to re-index most all sites.

You will just have to be patient.

The good news is that Google understands these sites rather well and will not take them too seriously. Low quality links are not the problem they used to be.

So relax and let Google do it's work. All will work out okay in the end.